# optimal probability distribution for a given set of observations

Tags: probability

I don't have much background in probability theory, so this may be a very naive question and I'll probably get some of the terminology wrong. I'm grateful for comments and responses of any kind!

===

Suppose I sample a random variable $N$ times, and I observe the value $x_i$ with frequency $n_i$. An immediate question is: What is the probability distribution that makes this outcome as likely as possible?

The obvious guess is the distribution that assigns probability $\frac{n_i}{N}$ to each outcome $x_i$. And indeed, I've convinced myself that this is correct, at least in the case of a discrete random variable. Specifically, if $x_i$ has some (as-yet unknown) probability $p_i$ of occurring, then the likelihood of this outcome is $\prod p_i^{n_i}$. I want to maximize this value, subject to the constraints that $\sum p_i = 1$ and $p_i \geq 0$. A fun exercise with Lagrange multipliers (that I won't spoil!) shows that indeed setting $p_i = \frac{n_i}{N}$ is the unique way of achieving the maximum likelihood.

While this is certainly convincing, it feels like it should be a tautology rather than a theorem. So, here's a(n admittedly slightly philosophical) question.

> **Question 1:** Is this a theorem, or a tautology?

Also, it seems slightly surprising to me that it might require calculus to prove something so intuitively clear -- although it *is* an optimization problem, after all.

> **Question 2:** Assuming this is a theorem, can it be proved without calculus?

I also wonder the following.

> **Question 3:** Is there an analog of this line of thinking that applies to *continuous* random variables?

For starters, if I still only have finitely many samples, I'd expect that the result above holds: the optimal distribution is actually just the extension by zero of a discrete distribution. But how can I prove this? And more interestingly, is there a limiting version of this as $N$ tends towards infinity?

Here's a final question.

> **Question 4:** What can be said if I sample without replacement?

Even in the discrete case this seems somewhat interesting. The only obvious guess is the same distribution as before. Presumably this could be proved directly, but I'd love to know if there's a slicker argument -- for instance, one that argues by induction on the first observation.

Comment: It is a theorem. You just found the maximum likelihood estimator for the multinomial distribution. There may be a way to prove it maximizes without an overt use of calculus. Maximum likelihood estimators are very popular and well studied.

Comment: Thanks, @Mason! That's helpful to know the term. I found the wikipedia page on "maximum likelihood estimation", which explains a lot. Just to make sure I understand, I have two small clarifying questions.

Comment: (1) You mention the multinomial distribution, whereas I did not; is your point that I was implicitly assuming that that's what I was sampling from? So for instance, one could also seek the MLE for a normal distribution, given a bunch of outcomes, and find the mean & standard deviation that maximize the likelihood of these data over all possible normal distributions.
(2) Just as a matter of terminology, what exactly is meant by an "estimator"? The wikipedia page seems to imply that it's the function from sets of observed values to probability distributions. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: (1) The distribution that maximizes the probability of seeing $x_i$ $n_i$ times with IID sampling has to be discrete, that is, is a multinomial distribution. (2) estimator is a vague term, that usually means any function of the sample intended to estimate a deterministic quantity.

Comment: @Mason Great, thank you!